# Не запускается эксплоит на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, взлом, уязвимости

Добрый день! Проблема в том, что не запускается эксплоит CVE-2015-1328, пробовала на двух версиях Ubuntu 9.04 и 12.04, компилируется, но не выполняется. Делала по примеру. В чем может быть дело? И как можно исправить, срочно надо показать на собственном примере выполнение эксплойта в Ubuntu :( [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так может уже все пропатчено ;-)

Comment: Ни в 9.04, ни в 12.04 необходимый для эксплоита overlayfs ещё не существовал, как я понимаю. Надо пробовать в хотя бы в 14.04 или 15.04, но старой, непропатченной версии

Comment: Я сохраню этот пост у себя в скрпабуке. Это прекрасно. В соседней теме чувак жалуется, что его томкат майнеры жрут, а тут рута получить не могут.